# How to remove elements from the $_POST array?

Tags: php, html, post, xhtml

I want to insert a record into a MySQL database table from a formulaire. The problem is that there is a `field` that is not in the table's columns in the `$_POST` variable but it's displayed as a `textfield` in the `formulaire`. I insert the fields values by this way :

```
$newRecord->insert($_POST); // we created a generic function insert($array) to insert records
```

So how to remove an element of the $_POST ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

simply go:

```
unset($_POST['field']);
```

Answer (score 2):

If `$_POST` contains user-entered data then I really hope that `insert` function is sanitising the data.  If not you're just asking for a SQL injection attack.